# Limit selection of picklist values to Flow usage only

Tags: picklist, custom-field

I have a picklist for type on Accounts, and I'd like to lock it down so some of the values are only accessible to be selected via Flow, or so that if a specific value is selected, ONLY flow can change it, and users can't change it directly.

Any suggestions? I'm not sure if a validation rule would prevent the flow as well, and I can't make the whole field read-only as some values need to be selectable.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a record type where only some of the values of the picklist   available to user on Lightning Record

For Flow you can create second record type where all the picklist values are available.

check the image attached.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer I was looking for: https://admin.salesforce.com/blog/2022/how-i-solved-it-bypass-validation-rules-in-flows

Comment: Links tend to become invalid over time, please reproduce the important parts of that blog here so that this answer can still be useful to people in years to come.

Comment: Salesforce in particular has a fairly bad reputation for breaking their links.